# Eclipse return just 10 first element Elasticsearch response

Tags: java, eclipse, elasticsearch

I'm using a java client api of elasticsearch

all my queries if the response is higher than 10 eclipse or list of object return just 10

and for aggregations also

there is any way to return the real result

for example when I execute this aggs query in kibana I got 19 and eclipse just 10

```
get /index/type/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_cat": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "categorie.keyword",
        "size":50
      }
    }
  }
}


SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch(indexName).setTypes(typeName)
                .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("distinct_sous_Categorie").size(100).field("sous_Categorie.keyword"))
                .get();
        System.out.println(response);
        Terms terms = response.getAggregations().get("distinct_sous_Categorie");

        List<String> distinctLineStatuts = new ArrayList<String>();
        // For each entry
        for (Terms.Bucket entry : terms.getBuckets()) {
            distinctLineStatuts.add(entry.getKey().toString()); // Term
            System.out.println(entry.getDocCount()); // Doc count
        }
        System.out.println(terms.getBuckets().size());
```

Comment: You do realize that eclipse is just an IDE, right? what does it have to do with the returned results?

Comment: insert it into a list

Comment: Please share your java code.